# How to change the UI if the value of a variable changes?

Tags: if-statement, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I tried to change the UI `if (variable1 == "1")`, but I get an **error**. Can anybody tell me what is wrong with my code or if there is another way to **show the user something different if `variable1` changes the value**? Below is the code I tried. Thanks in advance.

```
    return Scaffold(

      body: Container(
        if (variable1 == "1") {
        child: Center(
          child: Text("Test");
        ),
       }
        else {
          print("test");
        }
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

Using tenary operator in dart:

```
 return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: variable1 == "1"
            ? Center(
                child: Text("Variable1 is equals to 1"),
              )
            : Text("Varibale1 is not 1"),
      ),
    );
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

For the small if conditions or like, you can do as suggested by @Random Guru. However, in case you have more complicated logic, then it might be a good idea to get the logic done before returning the widget. e.g.

```
body:_buildBody()



Widget _buildBody()
{
  if (variable1 == "1")
  {
     return Container(______); 
  }
  else
  {
     return Text(_____);
  }
}
```